# creating search method in xlrd

Tags: python, search, xlrd

I'm trying to make a search method for excel file and if the word found, program should print the whole row and 
the code is

```
from xlrd3 import open_workbook,cellname,empty_cell,XL_CELL_TEXT,error_text_from_code, cellnameabs, colname
book= open_workbook('s1.xls')
sheet=book.sheet_by_index(0)


def search():
    s=[]
    a=str(input("Enter Search : "))
    x= [a]
    for row in range(sheet.nrows):
        for col in range(sheet.ncols):
            s.append(str(sheet.cell(row,col).value))
            if x == s:
                for col in range(sheet.ncols):
                    s=[]
                    s.append(int((sheet.cell(row,col).value)))
                    print (s)
                    s=[]
            elif x != s:
                s=[]
    search()

search()
```

i have a problem that when it came to number it's printed as float like  10301.0 
and i want the user to search for the the exact number 10301  and to be shown as 10301 also

any advice please ?
Thanks